# How to make second fragment overlap on first fragment while fragment transistion

Tags: android-fragments, android-view, android, android-custom-view

I am working on fragment transition.  When I replace the first fragment with the second fragment, it is appearing below the first fragment.  I want it to move on top of first fragment.  How can I do this?

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(animEnter, animExit, animPopEnter, animPopExit);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentListView, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: did you tried the remove() API

Comment: no i don't want to remove first fragment instead i want second fragment to move on top of first fragment

Answer (score 10):

If you dont want to remove the first fragment you can use the add method instead and to place the 2nd on top of the 1st you need to reference the top most layout or use android.R.id.content

For example:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(animEnter, animExit, animPopEnter, animPopExit);
fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment,"MyStringIdentifierTag");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This will add "fragment" on top of whatever is currently visible without removing the first fragment.

Comment: How can the fragment be added to the top of a `FrameLayout` in the case where we don't want to fill the screen?

Comment: This is simply perfect answer